# Kentico Not Showing Added Pages from Visual Studio 2010

Tags: kentico

I am working with Kentico in Visual Studios (web project) on my local computer. When I add folders or files to the solution and then run it in the browser, the pages do not show up in the CMS desk or site manager. Am I creating these folders/files in the wrong place in the solution (ex: {directory of web project}/CMSPages/filename.aspx)? Or maybe have incorrect settings?

Comment: Like @dvanbale said, you need to be more specific. What are you trying to accomplish specifically; a custom module, template, etc.? By default, a page added in Visual Studio doesn't just show up in CMSDesk, that's not how Kentico and it's content system works. And yes, which version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the way how it works - the system has no idea about your pages if you place them on the file system. However, you can create ASPX page templates and then use then for the documents. Please see the [Devnet forum](http://devnet.kentico.com/Forums.aspx?forumid=57&threadid=28869)

Best regards,
Juraj Ondrus

Answer (score 0):

Where Do you want to use this page?

In the visitor sites or CMS Page

If you want to use visitor site you can create a webpart and add you webpart to the Page create on content tree.

If you want to use in the cmsdesk the you need to register your page in the module